# Chrome forcing HTTPS on resources?

Tags: google-chrome, https

Here is a curious phenomenon I witnessed in Chrome.

A couple of days ago I noticed that [my blog](https://blog.ram.rachum.com/) lost its styling. Probably can't load its stylesheet or other resources, right? I've set it up years ago and it used to work until recently.

I used Chrome's DevTools to investigate and it seems that loading `https://evilcorp.blog.ram.rachum.com/css/fonts.css` is failing.

I spoke with my webhost's support, and it turns out no HTTPS site is configured. After more investigation, it was never configured to be HTTPS.

I looked at the HTML source of my blog again. The fonts file it's referencing is `http://evilcorp.blog.ram.rachum.com/css/fonts.css` , note the lack of `https`. That link does work.

I can't understand why Chrome is trying to load the HTTPS version when it was explicitly given an HTTP URL. Is this new functionality? What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your blog has as its address `https://blog.ram.rachum.com/`, so that this is an
HTTPS page.

When an HTTPS page includes HTTP content, the HTTP portion can be read or modified
by attackers, even though the main page is served over HTTPS.
When an HTTPS page has HTTP content, its content is called "mixed".
The webpage is only partially encrypted, since some of the content is retrieved unencrypted over HTTP, so is deemed to be insecure.

Modern browsers nowadays block mixed content as insecure, in effect disabling HTTP links.

In Chrome, you may force it by using:

```
chrome.exe --allow-running-insecure-content
```

but you cannot force your users to run Chrome like that.

The best solution is to convert your page to using only HTTPS links.

Comment: Interesting, thank you. Do you know when was the point in time when browsers decided to automatically convert these HTTP resources to HTTPS? Is there a name to that kind of behavior? Because it's definitely not trivial, and wasn't done more than a few years ago.

Comment: This dates from July 2018 with Chrome 68 labeling every website not running HTTPS as “not secure” in the address bar.